# Optimizing Inner Join Queries

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization, inner-join

I have this query and i want to know if i can optimize it in some way because currently it takes a long time to execute (like 4/5 seconds)

```
SELECT *
FROM `posts` ml INNER JOIN
     posts_tag_one gt
     ON gt.post_id = ml.id AND gt.tag_id = 15 INNER JOIN 
     posts_tag_two gg
     ON gg.post_id = ml.id AND gg.tag_id = 5
WHERE active = '1' AND NOT ml.id = '639474'
ORDER BY ml.id DESC
LIMIT 5
```

I want to say the database it has like 600k+ posts, the posts_tag_one 5 milions records, the posts_tag_two 475k+ records.

That example i gave it's only with 2 joins but in some cases i have up to 4 joins so the other tables has like 300k-400k records.

I am using foregin keys and indexes for posts_tag_one, posts_tag_two tables but the query it's still slow.

Any advice would help. Thanks!

Comment: what are your indexes on those tables, if you have any? also provide `explain` result

Comment: confirm which table the "active = 1" is associated?  Implication is posts table (ml alias)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query) - and SELECT (and properly qualify) only the columns you actually want returned.

Comment: In addition, questions about query performance always require the EXPLAIN for the given query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By means of Transitive property (if a=b and b=c, then a=c), your ML.ID = GT.Post_ID = GG.Post_ID.  Since you are trying to pre-qualify specific tags, I would rewrite and try to see if cardinality of data may help by moving to a front position and using better indexes to optimize the query.  Also, MySQL has a nice keyword "STRAIGHT_JOIN" that tells the engine query the data in the order I tell you, dont think for me.  I have used many times and have seen significant improvement.

```
SELECT STRAIGHT_JOIN
        *
    FROM 
        posts_tag_two gg
            INNER JOIN posts_tag_one gt
                ON gg.post_id = gt.post_id
                AND gt.tag_id = 15
                INNER JOIN posts ml 
                    ON gt.post_id = ml.id
                    AND ml.active = 1
    WHERE 
            gg.tag_id = 5
        AND NOT gg.post_id = 639474
    ORDER BY
        gg.post_id DESC
    LIMIT 5
```

I would ensure the following table / multi-field indexes

```
table            index
Posts_Tag_One    ( tag_id, post_id )
Posts_Tag_Two    ( tag_id, post_id )
posts            ( id, active )
```

By starting with the Posts_Tag_Two table which you are pre-filtering for tag_id = 5, you are already cutting the list down to those pre-qualified FIRST.  Not by starting with ALL posts and seeing which qualify with the tag.

Second level join is to the POSTS_TAG_ONE table on same ID, but that level filtered by its Tag_ID = 15.

Only then does it even care to get to the POSTS table for active.

Since the order is based on the ID descending, and the Posts_tag_two table "post_id" is the same value as Posts.id, the index from the posts_tag_two table should return the record already pre-sorted.

HTH, and would be interested to know final performance difference.  Again, I have used STRAIGHT_JOIN many times with significant improvement in performance.  I also typically do NOT do "Select *" for all tables / all columns.  Get what you need.

FEEDBACK

@eshirvana, in MANY cases, yes, the optimizers do by default.  But sometimes, the designer knows a better the makeup of the data.  Lets take the scenario of POSTS in the lead-position.  You have a room of boxes for posts.  Each box contains say 10k records.  You have to go through all 10k records, then to the next box until you get through 400k records... again, just for example.  Once you find those, then it goes to the join on the filtered criteria for a specific tag.  Those too are ordered by ID so you have to do a one-to-one- correlation.  So which table stays in a primary position.

Now, by the index by tag, and one of the posts_tag tables (smaller by choice is #2).
Now, you have a room of boxes, but each box only has one tag within it.  If you have 300 tag IDs available, you have already cut out x-amount of records giving you just the small sample you pre-qualify to.

So now, the second posts table similarly is a room of boxes.  Their boxes are also broken down by tags.  So now you only have to grab box for tag #15.

So now you have two very finite sets of records that the JOIN can match on the ID that exists in both cases.  only once that is done do you ever need to go to the posts table, which by ID is going to be quick and direct.  But having the active status in the index, the engine never needs to go to any actual data pages to retrieve the data until all conditions are met.  Only then does it pull the record from the 3 respective tables being returned.

Comment: (id,active) ain't gonna help.

Comment: Isn't this the simplest thing that optimizers do by default?

Comment: @eshirvana, see my feedback response to help clarify.  I have seen queries with 20+ million records being joined to 22 different lookup tables go from choking the system after 24hrs to being completed in less than 2.5 hrs.

Comment: @DRapp Thanks for your explanation and help! I apreciate!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like `posts_tags` is a many-to-many mapping table?  It need two indexes:  `(post_id, tag_id)` and `(tag_id, post_id)`.  One of those should probably be the `PRIMARY KEY` (Having an auto_increment id is wasteful and slows things down).  The other should be `INDEX` (not `UNIQUE`).  More discussion:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table

But, why have both `posts_tag_two` and `posts_tag_one`?

In addition to those 'composite' keys, do not also have the single-column `(post_id)` or `(tag_id)`.

If `tag` is simply a short string, don't bother normalizing it; simply have it in the table.

For further discussion, please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each table.  And `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`.